# Am not understanding what is missing for TypeScript Drawer component

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to TypeScript and have been trying to learn as I continue to build an application.

The error I am seeing within VSCode is:

`Type '{ state: DrawerNavigationState<ParamListBase>; navigation: DrawerNavigationHelpers; descriptors: DrawerDescriptorMap; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)`

This error appears from `CustomDrawerContent`

The way my code is currently implemented is:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<RootDrawerParamList>();

const CustomDrawerContent = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hellow</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="RootDrawer" component={LandingStackNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

The type I created for this was `RootDrawerParamList`. Which is:

```
export type RootDrawerParamList = {
  RootDrawer: DrawerScreenProps<LandingStackParamList>;
};
```

What am I missing about this one? Thank you for helping me understanding how I should approach this type of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `{...props}` to `CustomDrawerContent` but it doesn't accept any props in your code (`const CustomDrawerContent = () => {`).

> The type I created for this was RootDrawerParamList. Which is:

That's unrelated but that's also incorrect. You need to specify types for any params you accept for the screen, but you have specified types for props for the screen. Params and props aren't the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of react-navigation are you using.

The type definition in the version I am using is:

```
export function createDrawerNavigator(
  routeConfigMap: NavigationRouteConfigMap,
  drawerConfig?: DrawerNavigatorConfig
): NavigationContainer;
```

Comment: The version is "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1". Would this be the same one? Also thank you for your reply and code sample

Comment: Also if you don't mind me asking where did you get the parameters information? I have been looking at the documentation and nothing is mentioned

Comment: It does seem the error goes away if I update `drawerContent` to `drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}` Kind of wonder if the error was due to the props it was receiving which wasn't being checked